# Unable to infer XSD from XML file .XML contain Multiple Namespaces

Tags: ssis

While loading an XML file in SSIS using an XML source component , i get an error while generating the XSD
The sample XML is

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!-- RSS generated by Radio UserLand v8.0.5 on 9/30/2002; 4:00:00 AM Pacific -->
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:blogChannel="http://backend.userland.com         /blogChannelModule">
    <channel>
    <title>Scripting News</title>
    <link>http://www.scripting.com/</link>
    <description>A weblog about scripting and stuff like that.</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <blogChannel:mySubscriptions>http://radio.weblogs.com/0001015  /gems/mySubscriptions.opml</blogChannel:mySubscriptions>
    <blogChannel:blink>http://diveintomark.org/</blogChannel:blink>
    <copyright>Copyright 1997-2002 Dave Winer</copyright>
   <lastBuildDate>Mon, 30 Sep 2002 11:00:00 GMT</lastBuildDate>
    <ttl>40</ttl>
    <item>
    <description>"rssflowersalignright"With any luck we should have one or two more days of namespaces stuff here on Scripting News.</description>
    <pubDate>Mon, 30 Sep 2002 01:56:02 GMT</pubDate>
    <guid>http://scriptingnews.userland.com/backissues/2002/09/29#When:6:56:02PM</guid>
    </item>
</channel>
```

Please let me know if there is a way to generate XSD other than SSIS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple namespaces in your XML file. At the top of your file you can see:

`"< ?xml version="1.0"?>
    < !-- RSS generated by Radio UserLand v8.0.5 on 9/30/2002; 4:00:00 AM Pacific -->
    < rss version="2.0" xmlns:blogChannel="http://backend.userland.com         /blogChannelModule">"`

If you open up the XML file in notepad, or some other editor, you can delete

`"< rss version="2.0" xmlns:blogChannel="http://backend.userland.com         /blogChannelModule">"`

The rss version line is declaring the file as rss. The problem is that the rss namespace declaration is bumping heads with the xml namespace declaration. Removing the rss line should allow you to load the file in SSIS and then generate the XSD.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I only see one "xmlns" declaration in this code. Doesn't that mean there is only one namespace? Or is there some kind of inherent namespace which in turn means that SSIS cannot import any xml file that contains "xmlns" in it. That's quite a problem. I would expect every XML document to contain at least one namespace declaration